# folder permissions begin modified during compilation with VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

I am currently using Visual Studio 2017 (community edition), and during the normal process of edit / compile/ debug it appears that permissions to output folders are begin modified, leading to the following warning and error:

```
warning : Access to the path 'XXXXX\release\module2.exe' is denied.
gl3w.c
Module2.cpp
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'Release\Module2.exe'
```

I have two solutions for this, the first is just to exit VS, delete the offending folders and contained files and then restart VS.  The second is to take ownership of the folder, adjust the permissions with `icacls` and this works for a brief time.

My quest is why is this happening, and how would I prevent it.

If there is a better forum to post this question in please, point me in that directions.

Edit-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

After doing a successful edit, build sequence I used the following Powershell command  to get information on the file

```
Get-ChildItem ./Debug -force | Select Name,Directory,@{Name="Owner";Expression={(Get-ACL $_.Fullname).Owner}},CreationTime,LastAccessTime
```

This returned the following:

```
Name           : Module2.exe
Directory      : D:\gnuhome\johnHopkins\EN605.667\module02\Module2Lab\Module2\Debug
Owner          : BORIC\ghuber
CreationTime   : 9/5/2019 8:54:01 PM
LastAccessTime : 9/5/2019 8:54:01 PM
```

Note that the owner is a what I would expect.  Now I attempted a debug, edit, compile sequence and the compilation failed with the error;

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'Debug\Module2.exe'
 Done building project "Module2.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
```

Repeating the above powershell command, I get:

```
Name           : Module2.exe
Directory      : D:\gnuhome\johnHopkins\EN605.667\module02\Module2Lab\Module2\Debug
Owner          :
CreationTime   : 9/5/2019 8:54:01 PM
LastAccessTime : 9/5/2019 8:54:01 PM
```

Note, that in this case the file has no owner.

Comment: is the process in use?

Comment: No (at least I think not).  I would let the debug session run to end (or stop using the stop debugging) and then close the console window that MS leaves so nicely hanging around.

Comment: Didn't you check the task manager to see whether there were any residual process? This problem is usually the last run of the program is still running and not completely quit, So the .exe file can not be overwritten. Are any threads used in programs? It's easy to forget to close threads when closing forms. Closing Windows does not mean that the program exits.

Comment: I didn't check task manager.  While it is possible that closing the application or terminating the debuggin session might leave an open process laying around, this application is a single-threaded minimal OpenGL/GLUT application.  Next time this happens I'll check task manager.

Comment: @Suarez Zhou Happened again, and I check with both Task Manager and Processes Explorer(sys internals), and I didn't see any residual processes lurking about.  Also, with Processes Explorer I am able to search for handles and I didn't find any handle related to what I was building.

Comment: When this error happened again, run the program manually in the folder(XXXXX\release\module2.exe, pay attention to Debug or Release) to see what errors will be reported.

Comment: @Suarez Zhou After a week of behaving normally, the issue popped back up.  Tried running the program manually in the folder and got the following error "You do not have permission to access XXXX\Release\module3.exe.  Contact you network administrator to request access".

Comment: @thurizas, It seems obvious that your machine is in a network, the administrator does not give you all the permissions, and this program needs some permissions to open, if you want to solve this problem simply, just contact the administrator to give you enough permissions. But it's strange why your program can't be opened occasionally. There should be sensitive code in your code that involves modifying registries and changing system settings.

Comment: @Suarez Zhou actually, this is my home machine, it not part of a domain.  Technically I would be the administrator of the machine, and I can fix the problem either by running as administrator, or using an elevated command prompt to adjust permissions etc.  Two issues however  (1) why is this an intermittent problem?  Like I said, I was able to work for about a week without this issue rearing its ugly head.  (2) even if I use an elevated command prompt and 'fix' the ownership and permission issues, the next compile-debug cycle will case the issue to reappear.